# Is it possible to connect 3 non-Apple monitors to a 2014 macbook pro retina without adding extra hardware

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

Like the title says - I already confirmed this to work with my 2012 macbook pro retina with 2x Dell U2515 2516x1440 and 1x ASUS VW199 1440x900 - but since Apple tech still states that it should not be possible, I wanted to hear if anyone had experiences with the 2014 model?

Even if you have experiences with 2013 or 2015 - feel free to answer!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you have the 13 inch or the 15 inch model - Apple supports two external monitors. One HDMP or Thunderbolt. The other Thunderbolt.

You'll need extra hardware to connect more displays or even ones that don't connect to the ports on the hardware.

See footnote 4 in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154

> MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012), and Mac Mini (Late 2012 and later) computers can use an HDMI-compatible device on it's HDMI port while using one Thunderbolt display, or they can use two Thunderbolt displays.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that it's not true - right now I'm running 3 monitors with my mid-2012 macbook pro retina :-)

Comment: @Spriz What hardware are you using to connect them? Also, you might be confusing "supported" with "possible" in what Apple and what I'm "saying".

Comment: I'm using one monitor with HDMI (one of the Dell monitors) an then one miniDP to VGA for the asus monitor and one miniDP to DP for the other Dell U2515.

Sorry for the confusing with supported and possible :-) If there's a picture, everything is great in my opinion :-D

Comment: @Spriz Aah - I was taking your requirement "without adding extra hardware" pretty literally. No dongles, no adapters, no splitters, no USB drivers. You can connect dozens of displays if you get the right connectors.

Comment: According to the Apple tech guys I've been talking to it's not supposed to work with both HDMI and display output in the 2 thunderbolt ports, so I'm afraid that it will stop working if I update to a newer model - have you seen a newer macbook pro run 3 external monitors without adding new external graphics cards?